# Kendo ComboBox inside Knockout foreach loop in multiple partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have a view that does the following:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(e => e.Items1WithLabels) @* Call partial *@
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items2WithLabels) @* Call partial *@
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items3WithLabels) @* Call partial *@

@* more stuff *@

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
      var data = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)));
      var vm = new viewModel(data); // created by js script
      ko.applyBindings(vm);

    });

        // validation and saving part (irrelevant)

  </script>
```

Partial views are different from each other only by the model type and look like below.

Kendo ComboBox was not rendering properly and [Telerik suggested](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/combobox/strange-behavior-inside-tbody---combobox-won%27t-open.aspx) I used post processing event.

```
@model AppName.ViewModels.Items1WithLabels

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: Items1, afterRender: initCombo1}">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="combo"/>             
        </td>
        @* Much more stuff, but omitting for simplicity
    </tr>
    @* Much more stuff, but omitting for simplicity
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Items1 are embedded into the viewModel, so I can access them as vm.Items1. I also have list of labels that needs to go into ComboBox as vm.Item1Labels, but according to telerik must use it in post-processing event, which is fine with me.

Essentially following telerik's advice I need to embed `initCombo1:` ... `initCombo2:` ... etc to my `ko.applyBindings(vm)`, but its already working with pre-built viewModel as you see above in the initial view to begin with.

If I do what telerik asks for, it will look something like this:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    Items1: vm.Items1,
    initCombo1: function (elements, item) {
        $(elements).find(".combo").kendoComboBox({
        dataSource: vm.Items1Labels,
        index: 3,
        placeholder: "Select ...",
        suggest: true
        });
    }
    Items2: vm.Items2,
    initCombo2: function (elements, item) {
        $(elements).find(".combo").kendoComboBox({
        dataSource: vm.Items2Labels,
        index: 1,
        placeholder: "Select ...",
        suggest: true
        });
    }
  });
```

This looks very artificial and unnecessary cluttered to me and I am not sure it will work at all, since its called from multiple partial views ...

Anybody who knows knockout really well, please please help ! How to do it right and elegant and so it will work at the end

Comment: Have you looked at the Knockout-Kendo bindings. I recently moved it to Kendo Labs here: http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/

Comment: Is it another library separate from Telerik and KnockoutJS altogether? No, I am not sure I want to introduce yet another library into my scripts folder, another level of complexity to deal with unless its makes my life much easier. Need to see examples of how to do what I am trying to do (kendo combobox inside knockout foreach in multiple partial views) in order to understand and maybe if its compelling enough to switch ...

Comment: It is a library of bindings that lets you do things like `<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: {}" />`.  This works properly in `foreach` and `template` scenarios. Custom bindings like this are generally the best way to work with widgets in KO.  Here are the docs specific to combo box: http://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html

Comment: @RPNiemeyer it looks good but will it work within the foreach loop. See the reason I had to use post-processing event in order for ComboBox to initialize properly (link in my question to telerik's solution). If not foreach, I wouldn't need to do any of that ... So the q-n is if it will work within foreach loop? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it works fine in a `foreach`. The key is that the custom binding runs its init function when the element is bound, so each widget is properly initialized.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer it worked as expected! Thank you very much. Can't find a way to add more options like 1. default selection (selection option 2 from the list) 2. prompt ("Please make your selection..." 3. etc. 
Also having difficulties with binding it back to MVC view model, return result is null :( which was the whole point of this exercise